# Right click to select text JTextPane

Tags: java, swing

In my JTextPane, when i select the text and right click; It gives the option to copy text. Below is the code:

```
public LogPane() {
    super();
    JPopupMenu pop = new JPopupMenu();
    final LogPane l = this;
    JMenuItem copy = new JMenuItem("Copy      CTRL+C");
    copy.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            selected = l.getSelectedText();
            if(selected==null)
                return;
            StringSelection clipString = new StringSelection(selected);
            clipbd.setContents(clipString,clipString);
        }

    }); 
    pop.add(copy);
    copy.setEnabled(true);
}
```

So on right click, it gives the option to copy text. But what I want is that, when no text is selected and the user right clicks- Copy option should not be shown. How should the change be incorporated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `PopupMenuListener` should do the trick.

```
public LogPane() {
    super();
    JPopupMenu pop = new JPopupMenu();
    final LogPane l = this;
    final JMenuItem copy = new JMenuItem("Copy      CTRL+C");
    copy.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            selected = l.getSelectedText();
            if(selected==null)
                return;
            StringSelection clipString = new StringSelection(selected);
            clipbd.setContents(clipString,clipString);
        }

    }); 
    pop.add(copy);
    pop.addPopupMenuListener(new PopupMenuListener() {
        public void popupMenuCanceled(PopupMenuEvent e) {}
        public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {}
        public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
            copy.setEnabled(l.getSelectedText() != null);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've shown the wrong portion of the code. The part of the code that matters is your `MouseListener`, i.e. what happens when you rightclick.

In that `MouseEvent`, you can check the selection of your `JTextPane`, using [JTextComponent.getSelectedText()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getSelectedText%28%29), i.e.

```
public void MouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
    if(me.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON2) {
         // This is the code you probably don't have yet
         // You may have to check this cast
         JTextComponent myComponent = (JTextComponent) me.getComponent();
         if (myComponent.getSelectedText() != null) {
             JPopupMenu theMenu = myComponent.getComponentPopupMenu();
             // Etc... you wrote this part already and said it works
         }
    }
}
```